# ACTION_SCREEN_ON - Find out if screen was turned on manually

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver listening for `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` broadcasts. After the screen goes off, I want to possibly do stuff, provided that the user actually ***used*** his phone.

Some apps, however, turn the screen on without asking for the users permission. For example if the phone lies on a desk and there's an incoming call, the screen goes on while the user possibly is in another room and does not even notice.

So basically, I want to make sure, that the user interacted with his phone between `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`. Is there any reliable and simple way how to do that?